# how to make a group of users of my app only be able to access a set of files in AWS S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, nestjs

If I want to make a group of users only be able to access a set of files in AWS S3, what should I do?

create a directory for each user group?
I'm doing a private tournament system.

an example to better expose my idea can be a chat, only people in that chat can see those images, I'm new to aws s3.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be an S3 pre-signed URL that you share with the group of users.

Here's the explanation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Here's an example of how to generate a pre-signed URL with the serverless application model and a sample frontend

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-s3-presigned-urls-aws-sam

Comment: thank you so much man it's just what i needed:)